# Name Sidekiq worker process with ECS task ID

Tags: docker, sidekiq, amazon-ecs

We use ECS for our applications, but the processes in the WebUI get rather useless names like `66ef25674344`. I'd prefer if they would be named after the ECS task ID they run in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Sidekiq uses for the process name either the `DYNO` environment variable (probably a Heroku thing) or the hostname of the server it's running in (see [source](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/7de6f4cc2f68ee3d0976588dadcad418e3dd3c85/lib/sidekiq/util.rb#L38)). In Docker, the hostname is set per default to the container ID, which doesn't really reflect anything we can see in the ECS UI.

If we set the `DYNO` envvar before the process starts, it'll be used as the process name. This can be still done in the `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`, so we don't need to parse JSON in a shell script or so:

```
if ENV.key?("ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE")
  ENV["DYNO"] = JSON.parse(
    File.read(ENV["ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE"])
  )["TaskARN"].split("/").last
end
```

Note that the `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE` envvar and file it refers to are disabled by default. [Here the guide to enable the metadata file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html#enable-metadata).